# caught Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

Tags: reactjs

```
import {SanityClient} from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client=  new SanityClient({
    
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
        dataset:'production',
        apiVersion:'2021-11-16',
        useCdn:true,
        token:process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
    });
```

I am unable to solve it, Please give me suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: have you added values in your .env files ?